# Is it insecure to make HMAC SHA1 message and corresponding hash public?

Tags: hmac, sha-1

Not sure about the security implications of making HMAC SHA1 message and corresponding hash public (secret would remain… secret)?

Evaluating if that would help an attacker crack algorithm.

Comment: What's trying to be kept secret? Without the key, an attacker will not be able to produce the tag/hash. When you do Encrypt-then-MAC, the message (the ciphertext) and tag are public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, HMAC is using a one way hash in a construction that avoids length extension attacks. But even without that: the key is only used as input to a **one way** hash algorithm. So getting the value of the key should be impossible if you have any set of input message and HMAC output.

To "crack the algorithm" you'd need to *analyze* the algorithm. But if you do that an attacker can just use their own set of inputs / outputs, including any key. Having the output just helps with verifying that the key would be correct. HMAC should be secure regardless.